# Webpack bundle `create-react-class` with react

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

I am using Webpack to create a bundle of libraries dynamically by passing the packages to include.
This works great with `react` and `react-dom`, but I can't get the source of `create-react-class`.

Here is my code:

```
processResource(includeDependencies) {
    var requireString = '';
    for(var i in includeDependencies) {
        requireString += 'require("' + includeDependencies[i] + '"); \n'
    }
    var outputMode = 'development';
    if(this.isProductionMode) { outputMode = 'production' }

    const config = {
        mode: outputMode,
        entry: { app: "./temp_index.js" },
        output: {
            filename: path.basename(input) + '.js',
            path: path.join(__dirname, 'webpack_assets')
        },
        plugins: [
            new VirtualModulePlugin({
                moduleName: './temp_index.js',
                contents: requireString,
            }),
        ],
    };
    const compiler = webpack(config);

  var result = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      compiler.run(function(err, stats) {
            if(err) {
                return reject(err);
            }
            resolve('ok');
        });
      });

      return result;
   }
}

 processResource(['react', 'react-dom', 'create-react-class'])
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'get the source of `create-react-class`'? Do you want to get the source code?

Comment: @VictorF yes. i want to create a bundle file dynamically

Comment: Does it fail or give any errors, or just doesn't put the code into the bundle file?

Comment: the file is not in the bundle.

Answer (score 0):

A tarball of the source code of `create-react-class` can be found [here](https://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-class/-/create-react-class-15.6.3.tgz).

You can see all the versions of `create-react-class` at http://registry.npmjs.org/create-react-class

EDIT:

`create-react-class` is only for environments not supporting ES6, though, so if you're using Babel you shouldn't need it

Comment: Thank you victor. i wish to crate a Bundle of dependencies passed as an array to the function ' processResource(['react', 'react-dom', 'create-react-class'])' the modules to bundle can be different each time